# Holomorphic proper maps from $B_n$ to $\Delta^k$, $k>n$

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables, holomorphic-functions

I am studying proper holomorphic maps: one result is that there are no proper holomorphic maps from $B_n$ to $\Delta^n$, i.e. from the open ball in $\mathbb C^n$ in the open polydisc. What if I increase the dimension on the right?

I can't come to an answer: for what I know, embedding theorems could hold, such that every ball can be embedded holomorphically into some polydisc in great dimension.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Why no proper holomorphic map from $B_n$ to $\Delta^n$?, isn't the inclusion $B_n\to \Delta^n$ such a map?

Comment: Well, the inclusion is not surjective; so pick a compact in $\Delta^n$ that intersects $B_n$ and its boundary (so it has points in and out of $B_n$): its preimage is not compact in $B_n$, since it approaches the boundary. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every ball can be holomorphically embedded into some polydisc of sufficiently high dimension.

More generally, Løw has proved that every strictly psudoconvex open subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb C^n$ with $C^2$ boundary can be properly holomorphically embedded into  a polydisc $P\subset \mathbb C^m$  of sufficiently high dimension $m\gt n$.
This result is Corollary 1, page 453 of Løw's Theorem 1 in [this 1985 Mathematische Zeitschrift article](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/pdfcache/PPN266833020_0190/PPN266833020_0190___LOG_0038.pdf).

**A complement**
Although it was not asked in the question let me mention that the result does not hold in the other direction:
If $m\gt1$ and $r\gt0$ there is no holomorphic proper map of a polydisc $P \subset \mathbb C^m$ into an  open ball $B\subset \mathbb C^r.$
This is part of Theorem 15.2.4, pages 306-307, of Rudins [Function Theory in the Unit Ball of $\mathbb C ^n$](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540682721).